# Hide html elements from bottom when dynamically adding content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a comments feed. As Default, I am hiding all comments more the 4. 
If there are more the 4 comments and I have clicked the show more anchor, max 4 more comments are shown. My problem is if I now add more comments dynamically the CSS hides the comments in the middle of the feed. The comment that has the fourth position gets hidden when I add a comment. But all the other comments that showed when you clicked the anchor is still showing. What I want is: Show only four comments on page load. If a comment is added before the anchor is ever clicked hide the fourth comment and show the new comment on top (Is working right now). If the anchor is clicked(No matter how many times) hide the last comment that is currently showing and show the new comment on top.  I have a working snippet down below. I hope I am making myself understood.

```js
var _divNum = jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div').length;
if (_divNum > 4) {
  $('.showMoreAnchorWrapper').fadeIn(300);
}

jQuery(document).on('click', '#showMoreAnchor', function() {

  jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div:hidden').slice(0, 4).slideDown(300);
  if (jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div').length === jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div:visible').length) {

    jQuery('#showMoreAnchor').fadeOut(300);
  }
});

jQuery(document).on('click', "#postButton", function(e) {
  var textAreaContent = jQuery("#textAreaInput").val().trim();
  var html = "<div class='commentAreaWrapper'><div class='titleStyle'><span class='imgWrapper'><img class='' style='min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px' src='' alt='Admin'></span>Admin</div><div class='commentArea'>" + textAreaContent + "</div></div>";

  jQuery(html).prependTo(".commentsWrapper").hide().slideDown();;

  var _divNum = jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div').length;
  if (_divNum > 4) {
    jQuery('.showMoreAnchorWrapper').fadeIn(300);
  }

});
```

```css
.globalWrapper {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.commentsWrapper {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #EBEDEF;
}

.commentArea {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: #D5D8DC;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight", "Segoe UI", "Segoe", Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

.titleStyle {
  padding-left: 8px;
  background-color: #FBF1E7;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

div.commentsWrapper>div:nth-child(1)>div.titleStyle {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.inputWrapper {
  //background-color:#EBEDEF;              
}

.imgWrapper {
  margin-right: 7px;
}

#textAreaInput {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 97%;
  height: 70px;
  ;
  resize: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0.4;
  padding-top: 0.4;
  padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

.buttonWrapper {
  margin - left: 10px;
  height: 35px;
}

#postButton {
  float: right;
}

.commentAreaWrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 94%;
}

.commentAreaWrapper:hover {
  /*box-shadow:10px 10px 10px;*/
  //border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  //border-right: 2px solid grey;
  //border-radius: 5px;
}

div.commentsWrapper>div:nth-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}

.showMoreAnchorWrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="globalWrapper">
  <div class="inputWrapper">
    <textarea id="textAreaInput">test test</textarea>

    <div class="buttonWrapper">
      <button id="postButton" type="button">Inlägg</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="commentsWrapper">
    <div class="commentAreaWrapper">
      <div class="titleStyle"><span class="imgWrapper"><img class="" style="min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px" src="" alt="Admin"></span>Admin</div>
      <div class="commentArea">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentAreaWrapper">
      <div class="titleStyle"><span class="imgWrapper"><img class="" style="min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px" src="" alt="Admin"></span> Admin</div>
      <div class="commentArea">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentAreaWrapper">
      <div class="titleStyle"><span class="imgWrapper"><img class="" style="min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px" src="" alt="Admin"></span>Admin</div>
      <div class="commentArea">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentAreaWrapper">
      <div class="titleStyle"><span class="imgWrapper"><img class="" style="min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px" src="" alt="Admin"></span>Admin</div>
      <div class="commentArea">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentAreaWrapper">
      <div class="titleStyle"><span class="imgWrapper"><img class="" style="min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px" src="" alt="Admin"></span>Unisight Admin</div>
      <div class="commentArea">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentAreaWrapper">
      <div class="titleStyle"><span class="imgWrapper"><img class="" style="min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px" src="" alt="Admin"></span>Admin</div>
      <div class="commentArea">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentAreaWrapper">
      <div class="titleStyle"><span class="imgWrapper"><img class="" style="min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px" src="" alt="Admin"></span>Admin</div>
      <div class="commentArea">7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="showMoreAnchorWrapper">
    <a href="#" id="showMoreAnchor">Visa fler</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace JS code with this and test I hope this will work according to your requiremnt :)

```
var _divNum = jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div').length;
if (_divNum > 4) {
    $('.showMoreAnchorWrapper').fadeIn(300);
}

jQuery(document).on('click', '#showMoreAnchor', function() {
    $($("#showMoreAnchor").parents(".globalWrapper")[0]).children(".commentsWrapper").attr("track", true);
    jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div:hidden').slice(0, 4).slideDown(300);
    if (jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div').length === jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div:visible').length) {

        jQuery('#showMoreAnchor').fadeOut(300);
    }
});

jQuery(document).on('click', "#postButton", function(e) {
    var textAreaContent = jQuery("#textAreaInput").val().trim();
    var html = "<div class='commentAreaWrapper'><div class='titleStyle'><span class='imgWrapper'><img class='' style='min-width:48px; min-height:48px; clip:rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); max-width:48px' src='' alt='Admin'></span>Admin</div><div class='commentArea'>" + textAreaContent + "</div></div>";

    jQuery(html).prependTo(".commentsWrapper").hide().slideDown();;
    if ($($("#showMoreAnchor").parents(".globalWrapper")[0]).children(".commentsWrapper").attr("track")) {
        var visibleBlocks = jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div:visible');
        var lastBlock = visibleBlocks[visibleBlocks.length - 1];
        $(lastBlock).css("display", "none")
        jQuery('#showMoreAnchor').fadeIn(300);
    };

    var _divNum = jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div').length;
    if (_divNum > 4) {
        jQuery('.showMoreAnchorWrapper').fadeIn(300);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you!!. Worked like a charm with some tweaks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to `#postButton` click event:

```
  // if more button was clicked      
  if (jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div:visible').length > 4) {
    // hide the last visible element
    jQuery('div.commentsWrapper > div:visible:last').fadeOut(300);
  }
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joehany/6kpootp4/1/)